# When does dbghelp loads symbol from path embeded in executable file

Tags: windows, debugging, debug-symbols

I have an application that loads debugging symbols using SymInitialize().

From information I found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680689%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) symbols are searched in following order:

```
1. Dir containing the module symbols are being loaded for;
2. _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable;
3. _NT_ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable
4. pdb file path embedded in binary file
```

I am having this symbol load behavior on some Windows 7 virtual machines, but on some symbols are not attempted to load from point 4.

I was using process monitor to get a list of paths process is trying to access.

Is there an option, or maybe prerequisite that has to be fulfilled for dbghelp API to load symbols from path embedded in executable?

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally I have come to conclusion that this is the order of paths symbols are searched trough:

```
1. Dir containing the module symbols are being loaded for;
2. _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable;
3. Sub-folders from 1 and 2:
    - dll and symbols/dll if symbols are searched for .dll file
    - exe and symbols/exe if symbols are searched for .exe file
```

If debugger is installed (VS2010 or WinDbg) path embedded in dll/exe is also searched also.

_NT_ALTERNATE_SYMBOL_PATH seams it is not used at all, but it can be dbghelper version specific.

Can someone share their experience on this topic? It seams there is more to this, but there are no articles on this topic.